# How to Update DNS Records Programatically

Tags: powershell, windows-7, dns, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to update a DNS Record which is at (I believe) the following path on the server:

```
ServerName -> Forward Lookup Zones -> domain.com -> test
```

Where the DNS record is called `test`, and is of type `Host(A)`.

I downloaded the `DNSShell` module from [here](http://dnsshell.codeplex.com/) and tried changing the 'Data' column of the DNS record (which contains an IP address) with this command:

```
Set-DNSRecord -Identity "test.domain.com"
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument "test.domain.com" does not match the "^\\.*\root\MicrosoftDNS:MicrosoftDNS_" pattern. Supply an argument that matches "^\\.*\root\MicrosoftDNS:MicrosoftDNS_" and try the command again.

So I updated the `Identity` parameter as follows:

```
Set-DNSRecord -Identity "\\Servername\root\MicrosoftDNS:MicrosoftDNS_"
```

But now I am seeing:

> Set-DNSRecord : Specified argument was out of the range of the valid values. Parameter name: Path

When I try adding a `-Path`, it says there is not such parameter! Does anyone know where I need to add the `test.domain.com` part of the DNS to tell the command which record to update? The documentation on this module is incomplete for this part of it and I can't seem to find any alternatives.

I can call `Get-DNSRecord` and see the record I need to update, but any attempts to `Set` are blocked because I have no idea how these paths are built.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to overcome this by using ye olde classic `CMD` command:

```
dnscmd /RecordAdd domain.com recordname RecordType /Aging /OpenAcl A 192.168.0.0
```

This adds a new record, and seems to do so even when another record with the same name (but different IP) exists.

So in my case, I will have to use `dnscmd` to first remove the existing record before adding a new one (as I actually just want to update the IP address of the existing record).

Command for removing DNS record :

```
dnscmd /recorddelete domain.com recordname
```

More details can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can use also default PowerShell module for DNS server from Microsoft, example would then look something like this:

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name "recordname" -IPv4Address "192.168.0.0" -ZoneName "domain.com" -AllowUpdateAny -AgeRecord
```

In case you need removal before that something like this should work:

```
Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "domain.com" -Name "recordname" -RRType "A" -Force
```

Comment: thanks for adding this - unfortunately this only works on Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Server 2012 R2 so I can't use it, but this may be helpful for others